# Soldering panel mount switches to PCB

Tags: switches

I am new to the PCB design and PCBs as a whole.

Is it possible to solder panel mount switches with solder lugs directly onto the PCB, given that the PCB holes are suitable for mounting? (Rectangular-lish holes made using a footprint of the switch.)

I  need the switches to soldered to the PCB. Is it possible or is there another solution to the issue?

The switches I'm talking about are similar to [these.](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/e-switch/RB141C1100/3778081?utm_source=snapeda&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_campaign=buynow) ( I am kind of committed to them.)

Comment: What current are you going to put through the switch ?
In theory it is possible just watch the current and adapt your traces accordingly.

Comment: no more than a few milliamps for sure

Comment: Then it's good you can go ahead, you will maybe have a bit of a pain to solder it on the pcb. Pay attention to the footprint you will draw

Answer (score 2):

Sure, especially if you do it by hand. Slots (oval holes) are routinely done on PCBs.

However there are some issues, depending on the material of the lugs. They are essentially designed for quick disconnects so soldering was not a priority for them. The material could be hard to solder or oxidized so some testing is needed.

Also the plastic could have heat issues (you need a lot of energy to head these lug). As before, test!

Check with the manufacturer, maybe they make a PCB solderable version.

Last, but not least… how do you intend to mount them? they plug *from the front* in the panel hole, but now you have the board on the back. Unless you solder them after mounting (which would be perfectly legit if you won't ever need to remove them)

If it's for a one shot project I'd go for it. If it's for mass production look for alternatives, it's not trivial.

I also read you'll be using them for low currents: these are usually power switches, they can have issues in the long time with very low currents since the contact is usually designed to be cleaned with the current. Check the datasheet for the *minimum* recommended current. Or simply use some substantial wetting current (10-20mA usually are enough)

Answer (score 2):

Find something like this:
[image]
<sub>[TERMINAL, FASTON PCB RECPT, 6.35 x 0.81M Farnell UK](https://uk.farnell.com/te-connectivity-amp/1217080-1/terminal-faston-pcb-recpt-6-35/dp/2118988?gclid=CjwKCAjwo8-SBhAlEiwAopc9Wws-0Lmj77sNMaMq5qZNouHmJx-w2o5dG651TzvOGoFqiaVocT2SYBoCs88QAvD_BwE&mckv=_dc%7Cpcrid%7C565482043082%7Cplid%7C%7Ckword%7C%7Cmatch%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7C2118988%7Cpgrid%7C129965253803%7Cptaid%7Cpla-1707592839797%7C&CMP=KNC-GUK-GEN-SHOPPING-SMART-AUTOMATION-HIGHROAS-Test860&gross_price=true)</sub>

and solder a pair of them to your PCB instead. Your switch then just plugs into these (which is after all what the switch manufacturer intended).

Comment: excellent idea, I use them but didn't happen to connect them to the switch mounting situation. it also solve the assembly issue